# What can I use instead LOP3 instructions for working with uint64_t data types and do 3 operand logical operations using one instruction?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, ptx

I am working on a project and need to do 3 operands logical operation with uint64_t data types.But lop3 ptx instruction works only with 32 bit data type(.b32).

[LOP3 documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#logic-and-shift-instructions-lop3)

What can I use instead LOP3 instructions for working with uint64_t data types and do 3 operand logical operations using one instruction?

Comment: You could write C code to do what you want. Then if you really want to, study the compiler ptx or sass output.

Comment: @RobertCrovella This a an instruction of lop3 -     asm("lop3.b32 %0, %1, %2, %3, 0x9A;" : "=r"(x10) : "r"(a6), "r"(x8), "r"(x7));
I want something like this with b64 type

Comment: That doesn't exist.

Comment: @talonmies thanks.and what instruction can I use for bitwise operations with variables. I want that that code work faster then C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I ... need to do 3 operands logical operation...

No, you don't *need* to do that. Remember any boolean function can be expressed using just AND, OR and NOT (or even just AND and NOT, or even just NOT-AND). These sets of binary and unary functions are [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

And - if you think you need this for speed - that's also unlikely. The compiler will probably optimize your logical operations anyhow.

> ... logical operation with uint64_t data types

You mean you want to apply logical operations to each one of the 64 bits independently? In that case, just treat such a value as 2 consecutive 32-bit values and do whatever you'd like to those, once for each half.

Comment: @arm: 1. Don't assume that would be faster. 2. Don't assume _this_ is where you need to optimize - first check what takes up most of the time in your execution. I'm 90% sure this ain't it and the benefit you may or may not get is negligible.

Comment: but I saw that lop 3 works more faster then 3 logical operation with variables.I want something like that.

Comment: "You saw"? You mean, you did not actually time your own application. Your desires are probably misplaced. Also, - PTX is not even the actually assembly language  used on GPUs. You don't even know what instructions eventually get executed.

Comment: no.I have tried it in my application and have seen that "x2 = a2 ^ a5; x3 = x2 & a6;" is faster with lop3 (not with C code).

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot and found nothing in ptx documentation that can do 3 operands logical operation. So I changed all datatypes to uint32_t in my code and it works perfectly faster.